# Finding a sum of force vectors

Tags: vectors, physics, mathematical-physics

Three forces $\overrightarrow{F}= 2N\hat{i} -5N\hat{j},$ $ \overrightarrow{R}=10N(cos\theta\ \hat{i} + sin\theta\ \hat{j}),$ and $\overrightarrow{W}=WN\hat{j},$ with $W>0$ sum up to zero.

Determine $\theta$ and $W$ and draw the force vector $\overrightarrow{R}$ clearly showing its direction.

---

So I have,

$\overrightarrow{0}=N(12\ cos\theta\ \hat{i} + 5W\ sin\theta\ \hat{j})$

I'm thinking maybe $W=\frac{12\ cos\theta}{5\ sin\theta}$

and plugging that in, I got

$0=12\ cos\theta + 12\ cos\theta = 24\ cos\theta$

...solve for $\theta$ but that doesn't feel right and I'm at a stand still.

Comment: How did you get 20 and -50?

Comment: @SeanHenderson I just noticed that. Editing now. I multiplied instead of added

Comment: @SeanHenderson I think I fixed it

Comment: We need to solve separately in x and y direction.

Comment: @NMBL Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

- $x$ direction: $2+10\cos \theta=0$
- $y$ direction: $-5+10\sin \theta+W=0$

then solve for $\theta$ and $W$.

Note that "$N$" indicates Newtons and then we can not consider that in the calculation.

Comment: ok... I'm not certain about this but does $arccos(-\frac{1}{5})=\theta$ and $W=5-\frac{20\sqrt{6}}{5}$ make sense?

Comment: @NMBL Recall that we need $W>0$. By a skecth for the forces we can see that $R$ can be directed in the second or third quadrant depending on W size. We have that $\cos \theta=-1/5$ and from $\sin^2 \theta = 1-\cos^2 \theta$ we can find that $\sin \theta=\pm 2\sqrt 6/5$ and then $W=5\pm 20\sqrt 6/5$. Since $W>0$ we choose  $W=5+ 20\sqrt 6/5$.